# Why is the linker presenting an error about MPMoviePlayerController when building my application?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

When I build, I'm receiving this error during the linking stage:

```
      ".objc_class_name_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:
          literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@MPMoviePlayerController in MovieDemoViewController.o
      "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
          _MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification$non_lazy_ptr in MovieDemoViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build failed (2 errors)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: no man i have this in my header file/

Comment: possible duplicate of [i found this error ? will u plz tell where am i wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574339/i-found-this-error-will-u-plz-tell-where-am-i-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably forgetting to link the MediaPlayer framework.  Right-click on your project, and choose the Add | Existing Frameworks... menu item.  Choose the MediaPlayer framework from that list.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

Comment: hi friendz tell me the way to save video file to iphone